# Slick2d fullscreen adds black bar

Tags: java, fullscreen, slick2d

I am trying to make my java slick2d game fullscreen capable. It launches into fullscreen fine initially with this code:

```
Container app = new Container(this);

DisplayMode current = Display.getDesktopDisplayMode();
System.out.println(current.getWidth() + "x" + current.getHeight());
Start.setFullscreen(current.getWidth(), current.getHeight());
app.setDisplayMode(Start.FULLSCREEN_WIDTH, Start.FULLSCREEN_HEIGHT, true);
app.setResizable(true);
app.setTargetFrameRate(60);
app.setClearEachFrame(true);
app.setAlwaysRender(false);

app.start();
```

(The Start class holds a few constant variables that the rest of the program references)

I can also turn off fullscreen in my update method with this code:

```
if (gc.getInput().isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)){
        if (gc.isFullscreen()){
            gc.setFullscreen(false);
        } else {
            AppGameContainer app = (AppGameContainer)gc;
            app.setDisplayMode(Start.FULLSCREEN_WIDTH, Start.FULLSCREEN_HEIGHT, true);
        }
    }
```

When I run the program and press escape, it becomes a window and looks fine but when I try to put it back into fullscreen mode, it occupies the whole screen but there is a black bar at the top of the window and the displaying area is squished to whatever size the window was. Here is a screenshot of this effect:

[image: Black bar effect]

Also, when I switch to fullscreen the console prints `INFO:Starting display 1440x900` which is the correct screen size of my display.

I am using a MacBook Air 13-inch running 10.9.2 (Mavericks).

Comment: Have you tried it on any other machines? Seems like a silly question, but it could be any number of things.  PS. Great looking Slick2D game!